Threejs - buscar material en objeto
Tengo este código donde pretendo buscar un material con cierto nombre, en este ejemplo sé que el índice del material es 0 y sin problema puedo asignarle un nuevo material.
¿Cómo puedo buscar un material con un nombre específico sin conocer su  índice en el array?
En otras palabras, quiero buscar un material con cierto nombre y si lo encuentra asignarle una nueva textura.
object.traverse( function( node ) {
  if (node.isMesh) {
    if ( node.material[0].name == 'COIN' ) {
      node.material = textura
    } 
  }
})

Gracias!

bueno mi sugerencia seria la siguiente para el forEach.. puedes repetir el segmento sobre el array de materiales del Mesh y comparar cada uno con el nombre deseado y si lo encuentras puedes asignar la nueva textura
object.traverse( function( node ) {
  if (node.isMesh) {
    node.material.forEach((material, index) => {
      if (material.name === 'COIN') {
        node.material[index] = textura;
      }
    });
  }
});

repites el segmento sobre cada material de node.material, si coincide con COIN se remplaza el material con la nueva textura, con eso puedes encontrar y remplazar el material si conocerlo ahora... Si node.material no es un array sino un objeto de un solo material puedes simplificar el código asi
object.traverse( function( node ) {
  if (node.isMesh) {
    if (node.material.name === 'COIN') {
      node.material = textura;
    }
  }
});


Gracias, me funciona perfecto con el parámetro del índice.

Para recorrer el arreglo de material y buscar uno por su nombre podes utilizar forEach
Ejemplo:
object.traverse( function( node ) {
  if (node.isMesh) {
    node.material.forEach((material) => {
      if (material.name == 'COIN' ) {
        node.material = textura
      }
    }) 
  }
})


Gracias... funciona perfecto!
